# What will return a for loop in NodeJS with await?

Tags: javascript, node.js, loops, for-loop

My question is the following: Will the ''for loop'' wait for the first await to be completed, or will it trigger all await messages at once?
Also, if the response is ''it will trigger all await messages'', how can I make it so if the code below gets triggered into a for loop, it waits for the await to be completed, and continue the for loop?

Best regards.

```js
    for(let i = 0; i < parseInt(args[1]); i++) {
        message.channel.send("Please write option number " + (i+1) + ".")
        await message.channel.awaitMessages(filter, {
            max: 1,
            time: 120000
        }).then(optionmessage => {
            try {
            optionmessage.first().content.push(optionsarray)
            } catch(err) {
                return message.channel.send("Time expired.")
            }
        })
    }
```

Comment: Add some `console.log()`s and replace `message.channel.awaitMessages(...)` with `new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, i*1000))` and see what happens: https://jsfiddle.net/t5kqr2f4/

Comment: So I guess it wouldn't wait. How can I make it wait while still using this format:
`for(let i = 0; i < parseInt(args[1]); i++) {` ? Thank you for your comment.

Comment: _"So I guess it wouldn't wait."_ - Did you test it? Just check the fiddle I added in my comment.

Comment: Oh so it would wait? sorry got confused by the first person who answered.

Comment: Just test it... Hit the fiddle link, check the script and what it does and check the console...

Comment: Or check zeros answer which does the same thing as my fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will wait. Imaging a code like this:

```js
(async function () {
  for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    await new Promise(r => setTimeout(r, 1000));
    console.log(i)
  }
  console.log("end")
})()
```

The line where `console.log(i)` is, it will be executed only once the promise in `await` is resolved; so you will have to wait one second to have `0` in the console, then another one second to have `1`, and so on.

In the same way, the `console.log("end")` will be executed only when the `for` loop ends (so only after `4` is logged in this example).

Answer (score 0):

No, for loop will not wait for the promise to resolve
You can achieve this with new "for await" loop

Comment: _"I don't think..."_ is never a good start for an answer

Comment: Ohh I am new here , I will keep that in mind thanks for the suggestion